# Transmission in idle or slow speed

Tags: performance, raspberry-pi, raspbian, bittorrent, transmission

I am running Transmission on Raspbian via the command line. `transmission-daemon` is running fine as well as downloading. However after the download is finished and seeding should start, the Raspberry Pi will idle or stay at very low seeding speed (~5kB/s).

The stock settings you get after installing are applied now. I am not sure which information to give else. Are there any settings to be made?

Comment: That behaviour is not necessarily a problem - if the torrent has many seeders or only a few downloaders or downloaders on slow connections or downloaders that have throttled their download speed or download many things at once, you will not be able to seed faster than they are able to receive.

Comment: Yes, but I doubt that every torrent I tried doesn't need seeders.